# Probabilty of damaged details

Tags: probability

There are 40 details in the factory and 5 out of them are damaged.
40 details are divided into 2 equal groups. What is the probability that one group will contain 3 and the other one 2 damaged details.

I've found that the probability of dividing 40 details into 2 groups is
is $\frac{40!}{20! * 2^{20}}$, and I can't continue from this point

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by probability of dividing the set in two groups. But the answer is
$$P = \frac{\#\text{ ways of splitting the set in two groups, s.t. one of them contains 3 broken details}}{\# \text{ ways of splitting the set in two groups}}$$
Finally, it's equal to
$$\frac{\binom{5}{3} \cdot \binom{40 - 5}{20 - 3}}{\binom{40}{20}}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have to compute the probability that in the first set we will have 2 or 3 damaged details (thus in the second set there will be the rest, including 3 or 2 damaged details respectivelly) and divide by the permutation of the sets.

$P=\frac{1}{2!} \Big(\frac{\binom{5}{2} \binom{35}{18}}{\binom{40}{20}}+\frac{\binom{5}{3} \binom{35}{17}}{\binom{40}{20}}\Big) = \frac{\binom{5}{2} \binom{35}{18}}{\binom{40}{20}}$

Answer (score 0):

The below image shows the probability of all combinations and the total sum is 1.  The required prob is the the third and fourth options of having 2 in one and 3 in the other.

[image]